# How do I execute a routine when in the IDE a user control's Enabled property is changed in the properties window?

Tags: .net, vb.net, user-controls, ide

There are 2 colors defined:

```
Private goBackColorEnabled As New Color
Private goBackColorDisabled As New Color
```

In my user control, I overload `Enabled`.

```
Private gbEnabled As Boolean

Public Overloads Property Enabled As Boolean
    Get
        Return gbEnabled
    End Get
    Set(bValue As Boolean)
        gbEnabled = bValue
        pRedraw()
    End Set
End Property
```

I want to react on a state change of `Enabled` by coloring the user control's background color with the appropriate color. (Well, a lot more needs to be done, so don't focus on this please.)

```
Private Sub pRedraw()
    'Draw the background color depending on the Enabled state.
    If gbEnabled Then
        Me.BackColor = goBackColorEnabled
    Else
        Me.BackColor = goBackColorDisabled
    End If

    ...
End Sub
```

When creating a test Windows Forms Application and dropping my control onto it, I can toggle between the 2 colors all right, with the help of a checkbox:

```
Private Sub cChkEnabled_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
    Handles cChkEnabled.CheckedChanged

    oMyControl.Enabled = cChkEnabled.Checked
End Sub
```

How do I also have my `pRedraw` routine executed in the IDE, when changing the `Enabled` value within the properties window with the selected user control?

Comment: That should happen automatically.

Comment: Is this is actually a custom control?  You have the `UserControls` tag but thats not the same thing.

Comment: @Plutonix, the project is of type Windows Forms Control Library. Which tag is better suited?

Comment: The Enabled property is special, the designer for a control cannot allow its value to change while the control is being designed.  Because that would prevent you from selecting the control.  It is being virtualized by the designer, the basic reason why you don't see the color change.  Fixing this is not simple by a long shot, you'd need a custom designer and somehow let your Paint method know what the design-time value is.  I seriously doubt this is practical.

Comment: @HansPassant, thank you. If it's by design, I guess I simply have to accept this behaviour. It simply was irritating to have no visual feedback as with the other properties. If you bother to turn your comment into an answer proper I'd accept it as the solution.